# Improve Argo parsing performance

Tags: argo

In testing with Swift 2.1, Argo parsing performance is particularly slow.

I have a model, `User` that has 20 fields. Some are collections. Should I try to break this up further?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the size of your model is what takes a long time. We've noticed that large blocks of JSON can take time to parse and decode. In the github repo (https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) there are 2 performance tests that parse and decode a 4.6MB file of JSON. Their performance currently on the master branch is about 2.5 seconds each which could potentially be 5s total time.

Do you have any numbers about the size of the JSON you are receiving or how long it is taking to parse?

This is also a performance enhancement coming to master soon that saves 30-40% on that time quoted above. That might also help.